# How to force BottomNavigationView label to multiline

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components, material-components-android, android-bottomnav

I have a `BottomNavigationView` with a long label text and it's not showing the full label.

I found that the label on `BottomNavigationView` has a `maxLines="1"`, but I don't know how to modify it to allow 2 lines label.

Comment: post your code!

Comment: I didn't make any changes to the regular BottomNavigation code. Because I don't know what to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently **there isn't** a way to change the `android:maxLines="1"` used by the items in `BottomNavigationMenuView`.

It is a workaround and it **can stop to work** with the future releases.

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);

for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
      BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
      TextView smallLabel = item.findViewById(R.id.smallLabel);
      TextView largeLabel = item.findViewById(R.id.largeLabel);

      smallLabel.setMaxLines(2);
      largeLabel.setMaxLines(2);
}
```

Just to explain.
It is the [layout](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/res/layout/design_bottom_navigation_item.xml) used by the `BottomNavigationView`. Here you can find:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/icon"
      ../>
  <com.google.android.material.internal.BaselineLayout
    ..>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/smallLabel"
        android:maxLines="1" 
        ../>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/largeLabel"
        android:maxLines="1"
        .../>
  </com.google.android.material.internal.BaselineLayout>
</merge>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also add your own `design_bottom_navigation_item.xml` in your project. Since the name is exactly the same, it will override the one from the design library. Just make sure that the IDs and View types are the same.

Just be aware that if they change the filename of the original in a later release of the library, the fix will not work anymore.